# NodeJS app: error 404 for scripts/main.js when trying to link

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, restful-url

When i go to posts index route (http://localhost:3000/posts), the main.js file served in /public/scripts folder is found, but when i go to the posts show route (...localhost:3000/posts/:id) or any other posts route, chrome's console throws an 404 error for main.js file. Apparently, it's trying to find /scripts  at the /views/posts directory.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWrxF.jpg

Here's my code

app.js:

```
var express                 = require("express"),
    app                     = express(),
    bodyParser              = require("body-parser"),
    mongoose                = require("mongoose"),
    methodOverride          = require("method-override");

var postRoutes              = require("./routes/posts");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));

app.use("/posts",postRoutes);

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("application server is running") 
});
```

routes/posts.js

```
var Post = require("../models/post");
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var middleware = require("../middleware");

//INDEX - show all colectives
    router.get("/", function(req, res){
        console.log("get request at /posts");
        Post.find({}, function(err, allPosts){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                res.render("posts/index", {posts: allPosts});
            } //if
        }); // Post.find
    }); //router.get


//NEW - show form for creating new post
    router.get("/new", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
        console.log("get request at /posts/new");
        res.render("posts/new");
    }); //router.get



//SHOW - show more info about a post
    router.get("/:id", function(req, res){
        console.log("get request at /posts/" + req.params.id);
        //find the post with provided id

    Post.findById(req.params.id).populate("comments").exec(function(err, foundPost){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("posts/show", {post: foundPost});
        } // if
    }); //Post.findByID
}); //router.get

//EDIT - show edit post view
    router.get("/:id/edit", middleware.checkPostOwnership, function(req, res){
        console.log("get request at /posts/" + req.params.id + "/edit");
        Post.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundPost){
            res.render("posts/edit", {post: foundPost});
        }); //Post.findById
    }); //router.get


module.exports = router;
```

views/posts/show.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="masterContainer">
            <div class="container">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
            <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
            <!-- Bootstrap's JavaScript-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/jquery.transit.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Sorry if i misused some programming terms, i'm new to web developing and not a native english speaker. Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a static express middleware to **app.js** to avoid problems like that.

```js
app.use('/scripts', express.static(_dirname + '/path/to/scripts'));
```

Basically, what that does is make sure that whichever level you are on your app, express will always know where to look for the folder **scripts**.

Comment: thanks! this one seems to have solved the problem along with @Raphael Serota's answer (adding / in front of src of script tag). Although i still have some doubts left since both 

app.use("/scripts", express.static( __dirname + "/public/scripts")); and
app.use("/scripts", express.static( __dirname + "/public")); work just fine. What would be the difference between one another?

Answer (score 2):

Add a `/` to the front of the `src` of your script tag.

`<script src="/scripts/main.js"></script>`

This way, that script tag always requests the same URL, no matter which page it's on.  If you omit the leading `/`, the actual URL requested is relative to the current URL. For example, if you're currently at `localhost:3000/foo/bar`, that script tag without the leading `/` would send a request to `/foo/scripts/main.js`.

Answer (score 0):

You should to check the availability of the file "script/main.js".

Look to views/posts/show.ejs:

```
<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
```

It looks like the server-side code works, but browser can't load this file on the path relative to the current route.